# What are the radii of circles centered on the $x$-axis tangent to $y=\pm\frac{1}{x}$?

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to find a chain of mutually tangent circles centered on the $x$-axis and tangent to the double hyperbola with equation $y=\pm\frac{1}{x}$. The first circle is easy, as the curves pass through $(\pm 1,\pm 1)$ meaning $r_0=\sqrt{2}$. I've found through brute force that $r_1\approx0.5$.

Comment: $y=\pm\frac{1}{x}$s are not lines.

Comment: Let us use a more precise terminology: you are looking for "a chain of mutually tangent circles centered on the $x$-axis and tangent to the double hyperbola with equation $y=\pm \frac1x$". More precisely, you would like to know the abscissas of the centers of these circle, from which one can easily deduce their radii, or vice versa.

Comment: Given a point on the x-axis, what is the distance to the hyperbola? A circle centered at that point with that radius will be tangent to the hyperbola. This might help.

Comment: @8bc3 457f 2:  Just be sure you realize that the distance from a point on the $x$ axis to the hyperbola is *not* the vertical distance!

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it is with a little calculus, let's look at the individual points on the hyperbola, $(a,f(a))$, with $f(x)=\frac 1 x$ for $a \ge 1$. A tangent circle to this point would have a line normal there that goes through its center. Here's the normal line:

$$y=\frac{-1}{f'(a)}(x-a)+f(a)$$

$$y=a^2(x-a)+\frac 1 a$$

The center of the circle would then lie at $(b,0)$ and so we can plug in to solve for it,

$$b=a-\frac{1}{a^3}$$

Altogether we now have the one point on the circle, $(a,\frac 1 a)$ and its center at $(a-\frac{1}{a^3}, 0)$ which is enough to get the radius,

$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{a^6}}$$

Here's a little [desmos demonstration](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/e3xmdcu8ow) that I had used to do a quick sanity check, thought it'd be worth sharing as well.

There is a slight caveat here, this gives the radius of the circle in terms of the $x$ coordinate of where it's tangent to the hyperbola, not in terms of  the $x$ coordinate of the center of the circle. Doing so would require solving for $a$ in terms of $b$ in $b=a-\frac{1}{a^3}$. This looks to have a closed form solution when put into wolfram alpha, but it's not pretty.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from @Merosity's answer, solving for $a$ the equation
$$ b=a-\frac{1}{a^3}$$ leads to very nasty expressions but, using $a_0=b$, the first iterate of Newton method is
$$a_{(2)}=b+\frac{b}{b^4+3}$$ the first iterate of Halley method is
$$a_{(3)}=b+\frac{b \left(b^4+3\right)}{b^8+6 b^4+3}$$ and the first iterate of Householder method is
$$a_{(4)}=b+\frac{b \left(b^8+6 b^4+3\right)}{b^{12}+9 b^8+15 b^4+1}$$

The next order (no name) would be
$$a_{(5)}=b+\frac{b^{12}+9 b^8+15 b^4+1}{b^3 \left(b^{12}+12 b^8+36 b^4+20\right)}$$

Trying for $b=1$, this would give
$$a_{(2)}=\frac 54 \qquad a_{(3)}=\frac 75 \qquad a_{(4)}=\frac{18}{13}\qquad a_{(5)}=\frac{95}{69}=1.37681$$ while the solution is $a=1.38028$.